# SQL Azure IP configuration

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

Is it possible to configure SQL Azure DB to only accept connections from my Azure virtual private network? I would like to give access to it for all VMs in this private network as well as users connecting via Point-to-Site VPN client.

Comment: Isn't that how it works by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Database is not part of your VNET (it's a separate service, so the individual IP addresses cannot be added to the firewall. While you *can* simply enable internal Azure endpoints to connect to your SQL Database connection, this would allow for any deployment within Azure to connect to your database.

If you have services running in one or more cloud services, you can open your database firewall for each individual service's VIP.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, only way to restrict access to Azure deployments outside of my virtual private network is to specify allow rules for each of my individual service's VIPS. Is that right?

Comment: Also, is there any way I can open my DB to the outside, but only via VPN client provided by MS?

Answer (score 0):

Everything you wanted to know about SQL Azure firewalls: [Azure SQL Database Firewall](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee621782.aspx)

Comment: The OP doesn't want to know everything about SQL Database firewall, just about filtering on internal IP addresses, and not the global Azure internal IP address space. And that particular web page doesn't talk about individual internal IP addresses, so there's no answer contained there.

Comment: Sure it does.  It links to this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ff951635.aspx which does allow individual IP addresses to be specified.

Comment: Yes, but that's for Individual *external* IP addresses. You cannot specify internal IP addresses to filter on, in the SQL Database firewall. And the original question is about adding IP addresses from a Virtual Network, and that means *internal* IP addresses.